# UART communication in Gem5 with ARM Bare-metal

Tags: c++, qemu, uart, bare-metal, gem5

I am currently working with Gem5 and I have to access via UART from my Host to ARMv8 bare-metal option, so i tried lots way but i stocked yet.

could you please let me know, how can i map my host's Serial port to ARMv8's Serial Port in bare-metal type programming.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: ARMs do not contain uarts, the uart is a peripheral added on by the chip vendor...and specific to that chip and that vendor...

Comment: you have uart tagged and gem5 so you have the source code to the simulated systems, you can examine that to find where the uart is and simply talk to it...often in these simulated environments you can cheat and blast characters to the tx buffer and not wait for tx empty, making it easier initially to implement (likewise often dont have to setup the baud rate or other settings just start blasting, YMMV).  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually I am looking for using Uart for fully communication with gem5 FS simulator. how can read and write data from outside environment with inside of simulate system.

Answer (score 3):

**Working setups**

[This repository contains a highly automated working example](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/7d6f8c3884a4b4170aa274b986caae55b1bebaaf#baremetal-setup-getting-started). Features:

- works on both QEMU and gem5
- works on both arm and aarch64
- newlib allows using the standard C library optionally
- semihosting exemplified
- works on both `RealViewPBX` and `VExpress_GEM5_V1`. You should prefer `VExpress_GEM5_V1` as it is a more modern platform.
- pristine toolchain built with crosstool-NG

Key implementation points are described below.

https://github.com/tukl-msd/gem5.bare-metal contains another working setup and is more minimal, but it has less features currently.

**arm**

There is nothing special for ARM, you just need to find out the UART address and entry point address, exactly as for QEMU, and then pass the `--bare-metal` option to `fs.py`:

```
fs.py --bare-metal
```

The UART address can be found on the gem5 source code [`src/dev/arm/RealView.py`](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/7bfb7f3a43f382eb49853f47b140bfd6caad0fb8/src/dev/arm/RealView.py):

```
class RealViewPBX(RealView):
    uart = Pl011(pio_addr=0x10009000, int_num=44)

class VExpress_GEM5_V1(RealView):
    uart0 = Pl011(pio_addr=0x1c090000, int_num=37)
```

The entry point is deduced from the ELF directly, but TODO some values are not valid. I just step debugged until I found [these values](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/7d6f8c3884a4b4170aa274b986caae55b1bebaaf/build-baremetal#L81):

```
    if common.machine == 'VExpress_GEM5_V1':
        entry_address = 0x80000000
    elif common.machine == 'RealViewPBX':
        entry_address = 0x10000
```

**aarch64**

Similar to `arm`, but requires a few extra steps.

First you must build your toolchain yourself if you want Newlib since Ubuntu does not have the aarch64 package. I've adapted the existing arm config and reached [this working config](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/7d6f8c3884a4b4170aa274b986caae55b1bebaaf/crosstool_ng_config/aarch64).

Then, as of 6fa49382ef22e1b01fb24503e3bbe5ab3556750a you must pass the CLI options:

```
fs.py --param 'system.highest_el_is_64 = True' \
      --param 'system.auto_reset_addr = True' \
      --bare-metal
```

(`auto_reset_addr_64` before 6fa49382ef22e1b01fb24503e3bbe5ab3556750a) otherwise it fails with:

```
fatal: Kernel is mapped to invalid location (not memory). kernelStart 0x(400000) - kernelEnd 0x(0) 0x400000:0
```

The other key patch is: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/commit/3c3ca64b5f0dd9eef7b1ce1c65cc6e8e9147dd38

Alternatively, you could also patch `fs.py` as:

```
diff --git a/configs/example/fs.py b/configs/example/fs.py
index 3997ed76c..286e0bca6 100644
--- a/configs/example/fs.py
+++ b/configs/example/fs.py
@@ -376,5 +376,9 @@ if buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] == "arm" and options.generate_dtb:
             sys = getattr(root, sysname)
             sys.dtb_filename = create_dtb_for_system(sys, '%s.dtb' % sysname)

+from m5.objects import ArmSemihosting
+test_sys.semihosting = ArmSemihosting()
+test_sys.highest_el_is_64 = True
+test_sys.auto_reset_addr_64 = True
 Simulation.setWorkCountOptions(test_sys, options)
 Simulation.run(options, root, test_sys, FutureClass)
```

The semihosting part is optional, but super convenient, see: [How to enable ARM semihosting in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475268/how-to-enable-arm-semihosting-in-gem5) The other options are mandatory.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 host.