# Why would a simple C program need syscalls?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, system-calls, gem5

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256193/missing-syscalls-in-gem5-arm) other question. I am trying to run this simple C program in gem5:

```
int main() {
    int a=1, b=2;
    int c=a+b;
    return c;
}
```

And it fails because gem5 doesn't have some syscalls implemented.

My question is, why would a simple program like this require syscalls? This should run bare-metal without trouble. Is there a way to compile this to avoid syscalls? I am using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -DUNIX to compile it.

Comment: Try compiling with `-nodefaultlibs`

Comment: `-ffreestanding`?

Comment: `-nodefaultlibs` is giving me some errors:

`/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `__libc_start_main'
(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `abort'
(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_fini'
(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `__libc_csu_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: `-ffreestanding` still gives me issues. Standalone gem5 complains about it being dinamic: `fatal: Unable to open dynamic executable's interpreter.`. Combined with `-static` it compiles it using syscalls.

Comment: disassemble the program to see where the syscalls if any are, then work to remove them.  it may just be an assumption, building a program for this platform you are likley going to need syscalls so lets just setup the infrastructure in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without syscalls the program cannot exit. The way it works is typically something like this:

```
// Not how it's actually implemented... just a sketch.
void _start() {
    char **argv = ...;
    int argc = ...;
    // ... other initialization code ...
    int retcode = main(argc, argv);
    exit(retcode);
}
```

The exact details depend on the operating system, but `exit()`, which terminates the process, typically has to be a system call or is implemented with system calls.

Note that this is true for "hosted" C implementations, not for "freestanding" C implementations, and is highly operating-system specific. There are freestanding C implementations can run on bare metal, but hosted C implementations usually need an operating system.

You can compile without standard libraries and without the runtime but your entry point cannot return... there is nothing to return to, without a runtime.

### Creating a baremetal program

It is generally possible to compile programs capable of running baremetal.

- Use `-ffreestanding`. This makes GCC generate code that does not assume that the standard library is available (and has other effects).
- Use `-nostdlib`. This will prevent GCC from linking with the standard library. Note that `memcmp`, `memset`, `memcpy`, and `memmove` calls may be generated anyway, so you may have to provide these yourself.

At this point you can write your program, but you typically have to use `_start` instead of `main`:

```
void _start(void) {
    while (1) { }
}
```

Note that you can't return from `_start`! Think about it... there is nowhere to return to. When you compile a program like this you can see that it doesn't use any system calls and doesn't have a loader.

```
$ gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib test.c
```

We can verify that it loads no libraries:

```
$ ldd a.out                              
    statically linked
$ readelf -d a.out 

Dynamic section at offset 0xf30 contains 8 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x278
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x2b0
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x298
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              1 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: PIE
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

We can also see that it doesn't contain any code that makes system calls:

```
$ objdump -d a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000002c0 <_start>:
 2c0:   eb fe                   jmp    2c0 <_start>
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. While this helps me understand better what's happening I think my problem will not be solved until the syscalls are implemented in gem5, or I run gem5 Full System. gem5 is not being able to run the bare-metal code for now. My problem is gem5's limitations.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, why would a simple program like this require syscalls?

The run-time loader `ld.so` does syscalls. The C run-time does syscalls. Do `strace <application>` and see.

Answer (score 2):

There are some parameters to gcc you might want to checkout. Among others:

- -ffreestanding
- -nostdlib
- -nodefaultlibs

> My question is, why would a simple program like this require syscalls?

Because entering main and exiting the program is based on syscalls.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi solved the issue. Apparently uclibc implementation doesn't use the syscalls that gem5 doesn't have implemented.