# Build gem5 in 32-bit mode

Tags: 32-bit, gem5

I am new to gem5. There is an application that is compiled for 32-bit architecture that I want to run on gem5. So, I am trying to build gem5 in 32-bit mode. Is there any option to build gem5 in 32-bit mode?

Comment: There is also an interesting assert `if (kernel->getArch() == ObjectFile::I386)
        fatal("Loading a 32 bit x86 kernel is not supported.\n");` in `src/arch/x86/system.cc` at 200281b08ca21f0d2678e23063f088960d3c0819 which likely implies that you can't run 32-bit Linux kernel on X86.

Comment: For ARM, I've found that `root.system.highest_el_is_64=True` determines if the boot starts in 32 or 64 bit mode, and it seems that the stat can swap at any time, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682311/uart-communication-in-gem5-with-arm-bare-metal/50983650#50983650

Answer (score 0):

I also came to this problem and didnt know what to do, couldnt find anything in the docs or any other tutorials.

I've got it to work, but it's quite dirty.

I edited `src/arch/riscv/RiscvISA.py` and changed the default `riscv_type`

```
riscv_type = Param.RiscvType("RV64", "RV32 or RV64")
```

**to...**

```
riscv_type = Param.RiscvType("RV32", "RV32 or RV64")
```

and rebuilt with:

```
scons build/RISCV/gem5.opt -j$(nproc)
```

There has to be some way to add the parameters while building or something like that, couldn't figure it out but this workaround works.